# API Permissions have no effect on Java ME 8.2

Tags: java-me

I'm trying to access UART3 device on FRDM-K64F, I observed API permissions have no effect on it.
I can open the device successfully using below code, without adding permissions in project.
What does it mean ? anyhow how I can't READ/WRITE to the device with/without API permissions. Any Idea Why I can't read/write on UART3 !?

```
    int UART_DEVICE_ID = 100; //device id for UART3
    int UART_BAUD_RATE = 9600;
    int UART_DATA_BITS = UARTConfig.DATABITS_8;
    int UART_PARITY_BIT = UARTConfig.PARITY_NONE;
    int UART_STOP_BIT = UARTConfig.STOPBITS_1;

        uart = (UART) DeviceManager.open(UART_DEVICE_ID);
        uart.setBaudRate(UART_BAUD_RATE);
        uart.setDataBits(UART_DATA_BITS);
        uart.setParity(UART_PARITY_BIT);
        uart.setStopBits(UART_STOP_BIT);
        uart.setReceiveTimeout(500);
```